# How to connect to a wireless display (my Smart TV) with Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, display

I'm new on Linux. I've installed Linux Mint 17 and I don't know how to connect wirelessly to my Smart TV.

With Windows is so easy: connect to a wireless display -> select your device, done.

How can I connect it with Linux?

Comment: I am researching exactly the same thing. It looks like the various attempts at bringing Intel's WiDi to Linux (Miracast etc) have all fallen by the wayside. There are a number of attempts at pushing video to AppleTV (https://github.com/jamesdlow/open-airplay) but even these seem rather less than successful.

Comment: My current project is to get a RaspberryPi powered off the SmartTV's USB port to run VLC on demand to play a VLC streamed desktop from my broadcasting device. It's early days yet - I can do it all manually but I'm trying to pull together a solution which will kick off the stream, connect to the Pi and auto start the play. Some references I've been working on include this suggestion: https://ifoundthesolution.blogspot.co.uk/2008/02/screencasting-using-vlc.html and of course, the VLC documentation https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo_New/#Streaming_using_the_GUI

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any solution yet. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/341907/using-intel-wireless-display-widi-in-ubuntu

Comment: https://01.org/wds

Answer (score 4):

For Linux Mint, you can download 'Gnome Network Displays' from Software Manager.  After downloading, it will show you other devices in the same Network in 'Available Video Sinks' (thus, it must be the same WLAN for both devices!).

Screenshots of someone else checking this answer:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you then see two screens on the TV, but just one on your monitor, restart the Gnome Network Displays app and try again.